# Binding DataTemplate to DataGridColumn CellTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datatemplate, datagridcolumn

I am trying to setup a DatePicker DataGrid column in the code.  This column is used with different DataGrids, each displaying  different types of objects.  From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/627532/340045) I came up with the following code, which works ok:

```
public DataGridColumn GetDataGridColumn(string header, bool isReadOnly, string fieldName)
{
    DataGridTemplateColumn dgCol = new DataGridTemplateColumn();
    dgCol.Header = header;
    dgCol.IsReadOnly = isReadOnly;

    FrameworkElementFactory dateFactory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(DatePicker));
    dateFactory.SetBinding(DatePicker.SelectedDateProperty, new Binding(fieldName));
    dateFactory.SetValue(DatePicker.IsEnabledProperty, !isReadOnly);

    DataTemplate cellTemplate = new DataTemplate();
    cellTemplate.VisualTree = dateFactory;

    dgCol.CellTemplate = cellTemplate;

    return dgCol;
}
```

However, since `FrameworkElementFactory` is [a deprecated way to programmatically create templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelementfactory(v=vs.110).aspx) then I thought I had better search for another approach.

As an alternative I thought about creating a set of DataTemplates as resources and then applying these in the code.  This is where I have got to so far but I am not sure how to set up the bindings.  Here is my DatePicker template:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="DatePickerColumnCellTemplate">
    <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding Path=StartDate}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

And here is the new `GetDataGridColumn` method:

```
public DataGridColumn GetDataGridColumn(string header, bool isReadOnly, string fieldName)
{
    DataGridTemplateColumn dgCol = new DataGridTemplateColumn();
    dgCol.Header = header;
    dgCol.IsReadOnly = isReadOnly;

    dgCol.CellTemplate = (DataTemplate)Application.Current.FindResource("DatePickerColumnCellTemplate");

    return dgCol;
}
```

This new approach seems to be a more elegant solution because now the UI design of the DatePicker column is defined in XAML and only *applied* using the code.  However, now my DatePicker column only displays the start date.  The `fieldName` argument in the method could be "StartDate" or "EndDate" or any other DateTime variable defined in the objects that are being displayed in the data grids.  Also I am not sure how to set the DatePicker `IsEnabled` property to the value of isReadOnly.

If you think this is not the best way to proceed then please let me know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since no answers have appeared here is the solution I have come up with.

I did not find a way to hook up the binding for the template created in XAML but instead started looking at what I was trying to do - create a DatePicker DataGridColumn.  So I created my own `DatePickerDataGridColumn` class by inheriting from the abstract base class for a data grid column:

```
public class DatePickerDataGridColumn : DataGridColumn
{
    public DatePickerDataGridColumn() : base() { }

    public BindingBase SelectedDateBinding { get { return _selectedDateBinding; } set { _selectedDateBinding = value; } }
    private BindingBase _selectedDateBinding = null;

    protected override FrameworkElement GenerateEditingElement(DataGridCell cell, object dataItem) { return null; }

    protected override FrameworkElement GenerateElement(DataGridCell cell, object dataItem)
    {
        DatePicker picker = new DatePicker();
        picker.IsEnabled = !IsReadOnly;
        picker.BorderThickness = new Thickness(0.0);

        if (SelectedDateBinding != null)
        {
            picker.SetBinding(DatePicker.SelectedDateProperty, SelectedDateBinding);
        }

        return picker;
    }
}
```

Then my GetDataGridColumn method became:

```
public override DataGridColumn GetDataGridColumn(string header, bool isReadOnly, string fieldName)
{
    DatePickerDataGridColumn dgCol = new DatePickerDataGridColumn();
    dgCol.Header = header;
    dgCol.IsReadOnly = isReadOnly;

    Binding b = new Binding(fieldName);
    if (isReadOnly) { b.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay; }
    dgCol.SelectedDateBinding = b;

    return dgCol;
}
```